# Monero wallet rpc deducts 10 XMR from address when I call the transfer function (incorrect amount)

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, transfer, php

When I try to call the `transfer` function over RPC with php-curl.
It sends the incorrect amount out of my subaddress.

Following code:

```
function send_xmr($from, $to, $xmr)
{

  $piconero = bcmul($xmr, '1000000000000');
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:28085/json_rpc");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:password');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"jsonrpc": "2.0","id": "0","method": "transfer","params": {"destinations": [{"amount": ' . $piconero . ',"address": "' . $to . '"}],
  "unlock_time": 0,"account_index": 0,"subaddr_indices": [' . $from . '],"priority": 3,"ring_size": 16}}');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  $output = curl_exec($ch);

  if ($output === FALSE) {
    echo 'cURL Error';
  }

  curl_close($ch);
  $txObj = json_decode($output);

  if (isset($txObj->error->code)) {
    $code = $txObj->error->code;
    if ($code == -17) {
      return 'insufficient-balance';
    } elseif ($code == -2) {
      return 'invalid-address';
    } else {
      return $txObj->error->message;
    }
  } else {
    return 'Ok';
  }
}
```

This is how i call the function:

```
send_xmr(3, 73a4nWuv.....9QrPubkn, 5);
```

To describe the problem:

When i call the function, it sends 5 XMR from 73a4nWuv.... to 73a4nWuv.....

The transaction is successful.
I receive the 5 XMR which was sent to that address

**BUT:**
There was an extra 5 XMR deducted from 73a4nWuv.... address.
I don't know why but in total its always 10 XMR.

If I sent 0.5 XMR to the account, I would receive 0.5 to that address and 9.5 XMR would go to the primary address of the wallet.

I tested this on stagenet and mainnet, it's both the same problem.

This is how I setup Monerod and wallet-rpc:

sudo ./monerod --prune-blockchain --stagenet

and then:

`start_mining 55YyQiqdyQnJxnMR4tP5x1C89QzdJuMPwYsTduktXDCNejP2kTjYKwqfPf4BPhfVT3Z8S38j21FB5LjHBvPA3RirNZWA59e 4`

My wallet-rpc:

```
sudo ./monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 28085 --rpc-login user:password --log-file logs/monero-wallet-rpc.log --max-log-files 2 --trusted-daemon --stagenet --daemon-address http://localhost:38081 --wallet-file main_wallet --password main_wallet
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 1 output with 10 XMR and send 5 XMR elsewhere, you will spend that 10 XMR output receiving 5 XMR as *change*. Your wallet's confirmed/spendable balance will be 5 XMR below what you expect until 10 blocks have elapsed.

Comment: I see,
This is actually a mistake I made in the question, but not in my code.
In my code I did it the correct way, with an array of integers.

So this isn't the solution.
Do you have any other idea why it automatically sends 10 XMR?

Comment: The first part of the answer explains the 10 XMR part of your question.

Comment: Ok sorry for the misunderstanding, 
Is there any way how I can improve my transfer function in PHP, to be able to send the accurate amount to the receiver address?

Not 10 XMR deducted from the address, but just the amount that gets passed as argument in the function.

Comment: "send the accurate amount to the receiver address" is already the case.